transposing within a Polars df lead to "TypeError: not yet implemented: Nested object types"
I have this data:
┌────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ col1       ┆ col2                                │
│ ---        ┆ ---                                 │
│ list[str]  ┆ list[list[str]]                     │
╞════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["a"]      ┆ [["a"]]                             │
│ ["b", "c"] ┆ [["b", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "c"] │
│ ["d"]      ┆ [["d"]]                             │
└────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘

I want to have all b's and all c's in the same list in in row 2, but as you can see the associations of b to b and c to c are not maintained in row 2. With pandas I used:
import pandas as pd

pddf = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"]],
                     "col2": [[["a"]], [["b", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "c"]], [["d"]]]})

pddf["col2"] = pddf["col2"].apply(lambda listed: pd.DataFrame(listed).transpose().values.tolist())

print(pddf)

#      col1                    col2
# 0     [a]                   [[a]]
# 1  [b, c]  [[b, b, b], [c, c, c]]
# 2     [d]                   [[d]]

This is the desired result. I am trying to do the same with polars, by replacing pddf.transpose().values.tolist() with pldf.transpose().to_numpy().tolist(), but I always get and TypeError: not yet implemented: Nested object types. Are there any workarounds? Here is the complete polars code:
import polars as pl

pldf = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"]],
                     "col2": [[["a"]], [["b", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "c"]], [["d"]]]})

pldf = pldf.with_columns(pl.col("col2").map_elements(lambda listed: pl.DataFrame(listed).transpose().to_numpy().tolist()))

print(pldf)

# TypeError: not yet implemented: Nested object types
# Hint: Try setting `strict=False` to allow passing data with mixed types.

Where would I need to apply the mentioned strict=False?
On an easier df pddf.transpose().values.tolist() and pldf.transpose().to_numpy().tolist() are the same:
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl

pd.DataFrame(
    {"col1": ["a", "b", "c"],
     "col2": ["d", "e", "f"]}
     ).transpose().values.tolist() == pl.DataFrame(
                                          {"col1": ["a", "b", "c"],
                                           "col2": ["d", "e", "f"]}
                                           ).transpose().to_numpy().tolist()

# True

Please keep as close as possible to the code, even though it's not ideal using .apply() or .map_elements(), but this is in a far greater project and I don't want to break anything else :).
(EDIT: I simplified the code a little since the second lambda wasn't really necessary for the question.)

As you've mentioned performance in the comments - this may also be of interest.
Building upon @Herick's answer - when you add an index and explode, you are guaranteed to have sorted data.
With sorted data, you can add a "row number per group" using  rle() - which can be significantly faster.

(some discussion here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/19089)

(df.with_row_index("row")
   .select("row", "col2")
   .explode("col2")
   .with_row_index()
   .explode("col2")
   .with_columns(
      pl.int_ranges(pl.col("index").rle().struct.field("len"))
        .flatten()
        .alias("list_idx")
   )
)

shape: (8, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ index ┆ row ┆ col2 ┆ list_idx │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ u32   ┆ u32 ┆ str  ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪═════╪══════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0   ┆ a    ┆ 0        │
│ 1     ┆ 1   ┆ b    ┆ 0        │
│ 1     ┆ 1   ┆ c    ┆ 1        │
│ 2     ┆ 1   ┆ b    ┆ 0        │
│ 2     ┆ 1   ┆ c    ┆ 1        │
│ 3     ┆ 1   ┆ b    ┆ 0        │
│ 3     ┆ 1   ┆ c    ┆ 1        │
│ 4     ┆ 2   ┆ d    ┆ 0        │
└───────┴─────┴──────┴──────────┘

.map_batches() can be used to wrap the frame exploding/group_by logic into an expression context.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "col1": [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"]],
    "col2": [[["a"]], [["b", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "c"]], [["d"]]],
    "col3": [[[1]], [[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]], [[8]]]
})

df.with_columns(
   pl.col("col2", "col3").map_batches(lambda s:
      s.to_frame()
       .with_row_index("row")
       .explode(pl.last())
       .with_row_index()
       .explode(pl.last())
       .with_columns(
          pl.int_ranges(pl.col("index").rle().struct.field("len"))
            .flatten()
            .alias("index")
       )
       .group_by("index", "row", maintain_order=True) # order required for "horizontal concat"
       .agg(pl.last())
       .group_by("row", maintain_order=True)          # order required for "horizontal concat"
       .agg(pl.last())
       .select(pl.last())
       .to_series() # must return a series
   )
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ col1       ┆ col2                            ┆ col3                   │
│ ---        ┆ ---                             ┆ ---                    │
│ list[str]  ┆ list[list[str]]                 ┆ list[list[i64]]        │
╞════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ ["a"]      ┆ [["a"]]                         ┆ [[1]]                  │
│ ["b", "c"] ┆ [["b", "b", "b"], ["c", "c", "… ┆ [[2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]] │
│ ["d"]      ┆ [["d"]]                         ┆ [[8]]                  │
└────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┘

As a basic comparison, if I sample 5_000_000 rows, I get:



name
time




map_elements
61.19s


map_batches
7.14s




Thanks for the answer, I'll also check this later. also rle() seems interesting. I always used pl.int_range(pl.len()).over('groupcolumn').

Yes, it only "works" if the groups are clustered together (or "sorted") into single "runs". Hopefully the int_range(pl.len()).over case can be sped up when the devs get time to take a look. cum_count used to be the "idiom" for this, but it changed and no longer propagates nulls, so it does not guarantee a unique number in all cases.

Did you also compare the performance of yours and @Herick's answer. Also would that be doable in a "oneliner" within an exisinst df.with_columns() expression ind an larger df? And is there a way to maintain the order of the columns while doing this?

That answer took 30.09s for me in the same comparison. (Timings can vary depending on data/hardware though, so it's something you'd need to try locally.) It's not really doable as a one-liner. You'd have to add another .select(df.columns) to get back the original order.

Well actually, you can ignore the previous comment. Wrapping the logic inside map_batches did not appear to add any overhead in my testing, compared to the concat version. That lets you write it as an "expression" without changing the original column order.

The downside of this solution is that it only seems to work for one column. In the old solution I could duplicate col2 and make an identically shaped col3 and then replace all "col2"with cols (setting cols = ["col2", "col3"] beforehand; for the select part it was .select("row", *cols)). This worked then for all columns in cols simultaneously. With the "one-liner" I couldn't make that work.

Yeah, it requires a few changes to allow multi input cols. Basically just replacing col2 with pl.last(). I'll have to re-test both approaches with multiple input columns to see if there is any time difference - I only tested a single column originally.

Here is a solution that fully stays within polars' expression API and doesn't delegate to (slow) native python.
The idea is to carefully explode the nested list column into a long string column (using pl.DataFrame.explode), carefully adding index columns along the way.
This allows us to keep track of the row/list/inner-list index of each element and aggregate the elements back into the expected result.
(
    df
    .with_row_index(name="row_idx")
    .explode("col2")
    .with_columns(
        pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("row_idx").alias("outer_list_idx")
    )
    .explode("col2")
    .with_columns(
        pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("row_idx", "outer_list_idx").alias("inner_list_idx")
    )
    .group_by("row_idx", "inner_list_idx", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.col("col1").first(),
        "col2"
    )
    .group_by("row_idx")
    .agg(
        pl.col("col1").first(),
        "col2"
    )
    .drop("row_idx")
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┐
│ col1       ┆ col2                             │
│ ---        ┆ ---                              │
│ list[str]  ┆ list[list[str]]                  │
╞════════════╪══════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["a"]      ┆ [["a"]]                          │
│ ["b", "c"] ┆ [["b", "b", "b"], ["c", "c", "c" │
│ ["d"]      ┆ [["d"]]                          │
└────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘


Wow, that’s crazy. Think I’ll have to digest this tomorrow. Could you speculate about the performance differences of these two ways?

@gernophil It's a common pattern to get around the fact that not all Polars expressions have a list equivalent (yet). Its a bit more complex here as we are handling nested list columns. See here and here for other examples :)

@gernophil I only ran a tentative benchmark using a dataframe with ~300.000 rows. The solution runs ~4x faster than the alternative using map_elements.

Here is how I would have done this. I would define a function transpose_nested(listed) to zip to transpose each inner list. Basically, the same thing as transpose().values.tolist() in pandas. THen, I would
map_elements(transpose_nested).
import polars as pl

pldf = pl.DataFrame({
    "col1": [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d"]],
    "col2": [[["a"]], [["b", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "c"]], [["d"]]]
})

print(pldf)

def transpose_nested(listed):
    return list(map(list, zip(*listed)))

pldf = pldf.with_columns(
    pl.col("col2").map_elements(transpose_nested)
)

print(pldf)


which returns your original data and the transformed one:
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ col1       ┆ col2                            │
│ ---        ┆ ---                             │
│ list[str]  ┆ list[list[str]]                 │
╞════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["a"]      ┆ [["a"]]                         │
│ ["b", "c"] ┆ [["b", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b",… │
│ ["d"]      ┆ [["d"]]                         │
└────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ col1       ┆ col2                            │
│ ---        ┆ ---                             │
│ list[str]  ┆ list[list[str]]                 │
╞════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["a"]      ┆ [["a"]]                         │
│ ["b", "c"] ┆ [["b", "b", "b"], ["c", "c", "… │
│ ["d"]      ┆ [["d"]]                         │
└────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘


Modified this to: pldf = pldf.with_columns(pl.lit(pldf["col2"].map_elements(lambda listed: list(map(list, zip(*listed))))).alias("col2")). This works. Thanks. Still weird there isn't build in way :).

I agree, it is weird. Your pldf = pldf.with_columns(pl.lit(pldf["col2"].map_elements(lambda listed: list(map(list, zip(*listed))))).alias("col2")) is how I wrote it to begin with. For the answer I made two steps to explain how it works.

If this answers your question, do mark it as accepted.
